# Is it possible to change a simple CheckStyle property without the need of a new XML file?

Tags: netbeans, checkstyle

Basically, I am happy with Checkstyle default configuration, the only thing I want to change is LineLength.max.

I tried to set the property `Checker.TreeWalker.LineLength.max=120` in the Netbeans options for Checkstyle.

Project specific options seems ignored. Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: Yeah, I gave up looking and made a copy of the SUN checkstyle XML file with LineLength modified...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, afaik, you must copy the entire configuration file and change the property in the copy. Sad but true ...